# Continuity of functions over an interval $I$

Tags: real-analysis

Have a question here, that I need a hand with. Suppose that f is continuous at $x=a$ and that $f(a) \neq 0$. I have to show that there is an open interval $I$ such that $a \in I$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in I$.

I was thinking of using the Archimedean Property at first, but this won't necessarily work since  $f(x)$ might equal zero between $a$ and the next whole number. 
I understand why this is true, as we can just make the interval $I$ smaller and smaller until none of the elements take $f(x)$ to zero. 
I just need a formal proof of it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the definition of continuity?

Comment: @user88595 Yeah. if a function f,is continuous at a, then $\lim_{x \to a} = f(a)$

Comment: @Crockett Do you know the **$\epsilon-\delta$** definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f(a) > 0$. If $f(a) < 0$ apply to the function $-f$.

Set $\epsilon = \frac{f(a)}{2}$

Then since $f$ is continuous at $a$ we know $\exists \eta>0$ so that when $x \in I $ we have $|x-a| < \eta \implies |f(x) -f(a)| < \frac{f(a)}{2}$.

Therefore we have when $x\in (a-\eta, a+\eta)$ it follows that $\frac{f(a)}{2} < f(x) < \frac{3f(a)}{2}.$

Since $f(a) >0$, it follows that $f(x)>0$ when $x \in (a-\eta,a+\eta)$, so we have found the interval desired.

Answer (score 1):

As $f$ is continuous at $a$, for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ with $|x-a|<\delta$. Let $\epsilon=|f(a)|$ and $I=(x-\delta,x+\delta)$.